# TransactionScope and "durable resources"

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

Quick question about the TransactionScope object. Found this on the internet:

> When you access your first durable resource manager, a lightweight
>   committable transaction is created to support the single transaction.
>   When you access a second durable resource manager, the transaction is
>   promoted to a distributed transaction.

That seems fine, but I didnt understand what exactly is a "durable resource". I know that TransactionScope only works with SQL Server 2005 and above so if I need to access SQL server 200, it wont be possible? How about a text file on the disk? I've always heard that you cant have transaction control when it involves disk access. Maybe is it different with this object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229975%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) discusses the differences between durable and volatile resource managers.

Just to clarify - TransactionScopes will work with [earlier versions of SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320986/transactionscope-error-against-sql-server-2000-the-partner-transaction-manager), however, the lightweight transaction manager only works for 2005+. DTC will be required for transactions to SQL 2000.

There is also support for transactional file systems (Vista and later) - have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289395/transactionscope-with-files-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 3):

Resource Managers are of two types

- **Durable**: transactions are durable even when system failures occur.Resource Managers memorize state of a transaction. If system is shut down in between then upon restart Transaction can proceed from its previous state. for e.g. SQL Server DBMS and MSMQ.
- **Volatile**: Non-resistant to system failures, e.g. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163688.aspx) transactional implementation of some core .Net classes.