# The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions in MSharp

Tags: exception, msdtc, m#

The main issue here makes it different from other available problems and solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321090/184572)) is that, I am working with a previously working M# project and right now after upgrading to M# v4.8.334 (or maybe some other modifications regarding Visual Studio 2017 installation), if I want to add any new fields to any entity in MSharp IDE, it gives the following error

> Base issue: The partner transaction manager has disabled its support
>   for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)

[image]

One important point to note is that for **newly created projects** it is working correctly without this exception so my **DTC settings** and service are configured correctly.

Updated:

[image: the image of currently configured MS DTC]

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your computer's MSDTC settings?

Comment: @Paymon, question is updated but actually the problem was with the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

- my main issue was my app SQL database **connection string** which I have changed it from default **local** instance in web app **web.config** , to remotely hosted production database and after changing back that connection string this issue gets resolved
- it is useful to note that there is another database with **.DesignTime** suffix which is created beside your app .temp database and I searched for designTime in content of  files in the project and did not found any trace of it, so it seems that you do not have much control over it and in design time maybe M# IDE is looking for it beside you db, beside the fact that DTC service must be running on remote server
- for anyone looking for more correct DTC setting which is recommended by MSharp company note the following image

[image]